# In Vue JS, call a filter from a method inside the vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say I have a Vue instance like so:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        word: 'foo',
    },

    filters: {
       capitalize: function(text) {
           return text.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
       }
    },

    methods: {
        sendData: function() {
            var payload = this.$filters.capitalize(this.word); // how?
        }
    }
}
```

I can easily use the filter in a template like so:

```
<span>The word is {{ word | capitalize }}</span>
```

But how can I use this filter from within an instance method or computed property?
(Obviously this example is trivial and my actual filters are more complex).

Answer (score 302):

```
this.$options.filters.capitalize(this.word);
```

See http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-options

Comment: This isn't working for me in a Nuxt context. `this.$options` doesn't have a `filters` property.

Comment: In NuxtJS use ```this.$root.$options.filters```

Answer (score 41):

This is what worked for me

1. Defining filter

   ```
   //credit to @Bill Criswell for this filter
   Vue.filter('truncate', function (text, stop, clamp) {
       return text.slice(0, stop) + (stop < text.length ? clamp || '...' : '')
   });
   ```
2. Using filter

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   let text = Vue.filter('truncate')(sometextToTruncate, 18);
   ```

Comment: The flaw in this answer is relying on `import Vue from 'vue'` and creating a new variable when one already exists.

Answer (score 22):

if your filter is something like this

```
<span>{{ count }} {{ 'item' | plural(count, 'items') }}</span>
```

this is the answer

```
this.$options.filters.plural('item', count, 'items')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `vuex` like helper function to map globally registered filters into the methods object of a vue component:

```
// map-filters.js
export function mapFilters(filters) {
    return filters.reduce((result, filter) => {
        result[filter] = function(...args) {
            return this.$options.filters[filter](...args);
        };
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import { mapFilters } from './map-filters';

export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapFilters(['linebreak'])
    }
}
```

Comment: This is bad use of the `reduce` method. It could be better done with a combination of `map` and `Object.entries`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
this.$options.filters.capitalize
```

Comment: How does this add anything to [the accepted answer posted 7 years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671045/6243352)?

Answer (score 1):

To complement Morris answer, this is an example of a file I normally use to put filters inside, you can use in any view using this method.

```
var Vue = window.Vue
var moment = window.moment

Vue.filter('fecha', value => {
  return moment.utc(value).local().format('DD MMM YY h:mm A')
})

Vue.filter('ago', value => {
  return moment.utc(value).local().fromNow()
})

Vue.filter('number', value => {
  const val = (value / 1).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')
  return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')
})
Vue.filter('size', value => {
  const val = (value / 1).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',')
  return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')
})
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to declare things in a global scope, which `windows.Vue` and `windows.moment` does, unless you absolutely have to, without any other way.

Comment: Not true at all for this topics! Globally defined filters per a project is a good rule !

Answer (score 0):

In vue3 you need to load your filters according to the documentation then access them in a computed property or method like this:

```
this.$filters.myFilterName(params)
```