# In Vue JS, call a filter from a method inside the vue instance but $options is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined

I've already seen this answer which fits my question : [In Vue JS, call a filter from a method inside the vue instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639312/in-vue-js-call-a-filter-from-a-method-inside-the-vue-instance)

Now with that out of the way, when doing

```
console.log(this.$options)
```

I get `undefined` so I can't call `filters` on it..
This is my code:

```
 methods:{
    style:(input)=>{
      return {
        backgroundColor:this.$options.filters.color(input),
      }
    }
  },
  filters: {
    color: function (value) {
      console.log(color(value));
      if (!value) return ''
      return `rgb(${value},${value},${value})`
    }
  }

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filters' of undefined"
```

Comment: I think may be your arrow function ! How about changing `style: function(input) {}`

Comment: you're absolutely right , figured it out in the end, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the arrow function for style method. It should be:

```
style(input) {
    return {
        backgroundColor:this.$options.filters.color(input),
    }
}
```

And if you are not using `this` within your filter then you can extract it outside like:

```
function color (value) {
    console.log(color(value));
    if (!value) return ''
    return `rgb(${value},${value},${value})`
}

methods: {
    style(input) {
        return {
            backgroundColor: color(input),
        }
    }
},
filters: { color }
```

Comment: the first part is the right answer even tho the second way of coding also makes sense
thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can write this function in methods

```
methods:{
    style:(input)=>{
      return {
        backgroundColor:this.color(input),
      }
    },
    color: (value) {
      console.log(color(value));
      if (!value) return ''
        return `rgb(${value},${value},${value})`
      }
  }
```