# Accessing Vue filters programmatically within render()

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

How does one access the filters defined on a Vue component (globally or locally) from within the `render` function? Neither the documentation nor a dump of `this` offer much help. The first trivial answer is to put the filter functions in an `export`, but that defeats the purpose of the Vue filter functionality. The second trivial answer is to `import Vue`, but that defeats the purpose of asking this in the first place.

The code in question is in a Nuxt context. I defined the filters in a file `~/plugin/filters.js`, and updated the `plugins` configuration point in nuxt.config.js to run `~/plugin/filters`.

`this.$options` does not have a `filters` property (although its prototype does).

I'm assuming `functional` must be false, but an answer that works for functional components is acceptable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vue JS, call a filter from a method inside the vue instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639312/in-vue-js-call-a-filter-from-a-method-inside-the-vue-instance)

Comment: it doesn't. `this.$options` doesn't have a `filters` property, and `import Vue` defeats the purpose of this question.

Comment: just a suggestion, whatever you are trying to do with filters, i recommend switching to methods instead, filters are deprecated in Vue3